# Single boto connection object for different aws services

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

Is it possible to create a single connection object to be used for different aws services ?
Each time a connection is made its a new api call so i believe it would save some time if a connection once created can be reused.

Comment: Its likely savings will be minimal. AWS API services are HTTP REST calls. An http connection is made when you make the call. Depending on the library, its may or may not be left open.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might be possible to use a single connection for multiple services, that's not how boto is written and as the comment above states, I doubt very much that it would improve your performance.  I would recommend that you create a single connection per service and keep reusing that connection.  Boto caches connections and will also handle any reconnection that might be required if you don't use the connection for a while or encounter some error.